# Visual Basic 2019 - Can you reference an object without its name?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

## I am programming chess, all of my objects are pictureboxes. I have all of the pictureboxes in a 2-dimensional array. If I get the name of the picturebox they click on, then substring the name to get the number it is (Example:54), can I use the number in order to reference a different picturbox
(Example: Dim intNum as integer = picClick.Name.Substring(3,2)
Dim strName as string = "pic" & intNum-8
Dim picNext as PicturBox = strName |or| picNext.Name = strName) Something similar to that. I know the 'picNext.Name = strName' doesn't work, because I have already tried it.
Another idea, would I be able to reference the picturebox using the tag property? I have all of the pictureboxes with tags from 0,0-7,7.
Bottom line is , Is there any way to reference/grab an object for future use, instead of using a ludicrous amount of If Structures. Sorry if formatting is weird.

```
[enter image description here][1]  
[enter image description here][2]   
[enter image description here][3]  
[enter image description here][4]

Public Class frmChess
Private strBoard(7, 7) As String, Click1 As PictureBox, Click2 As PictureBox, 
blnWhite As Boolean, bln1stClick As Boolean
Private Sub PictureBoxClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pic1.Click, 
pic2.Click, pic3.Click, pic4.Click, pic5.Click, pic6.Click, pic7.Click, 
pic8.Click, pic9.Click, pic10.Click, pic11.Click, pic12.Click, pic13.Click, 
pic14.Click, pic15.Click, pic16.Click, pic17.Click, pic18.Click, pic19.Click, 
pic20.Click, pic21.Click, pic22.Click, pic23.Click, pic24.Click, pic25.Click, 
pic26.Click, pic27.Click, pic28.Click, pic29.Click, pic30.Click, pic31.Click, 
pic32.Click, pic33.Click, pic34.Click, pic35.Click, pic36.Click, pic37.Click, 
pic38.Click, pic39.Click, pic40.Click, pic41.Click, pic42.Click, pic43.Click, 
pic44.Click, pic45.Click, pic46.Click, pic47.Click, pic48.Click, pic49.Click, 
pic50.Click, pic51.Click, pic52.Click, pic53.Click, pic54.Click, pic55.Click, 
pic56.Click, pic57.Click, pic58.Click, pic59.Click, pic60.Click, pic61.Click, 
pic62.Click, pic63.Click, pic64.Click
    Dim picClick As PictureBox = sender
    Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
    intRow = picClick.Tag.Substring(0, 1)
    intCol = picClick.Tag.substring(2, 1)
    If blnWhite = True Then
        If bln1stClick = True Then
            Click1 = picClick
            picClick.Enabled = False
            Dim intPlace As Integer = Click1.Name.Substring(3, 2)
            If strBoard(intRow, intCol) <> "" Then
                Dim strPiece As String = strBoard(intRow, intCol)
                If strPiece = "White Pawn" Then
                    If Click1.Tag Like "6,#" Then
                        'Two places
                        Dim strName As String, picNext As PictureBox

                        strName = "pic" & intPlace - 8
                        picNext.Name = strName
                        If strBoard(picNext.Tag.substring(0, 1), 
picNext.Tag.substring(2, 1)) <> "" Then
                            'No Change
                        Else
                            If intPlace - 8 = 42 Or intPlace - 8 = 44 Or intPlace 
- 8 = 46 Or intPlace - 8 = 48 Then 'Light Squares
                                picNext.Image = 
My.Resources.Light_Square_HighLightedMove
                            Else '41,43,45,47 | Dark Squares
                                picNext.Image = 
My.Resources.Dark_Square_HighLightedMove
                            End If
                            strName = "pic" & intPlace - 16
                            picNext.Name = strName
                            If intPlace - 16 = 33 Or intPlace - 16 = 35 Or 
intPlace - 16 = 37 Or intPlace - 16 = 39 Then 'Light Squares
                                picNext.Image = 
My.Resources.Light_Square_HighLightedMove
                            Else '34,36,38,40 | Dark Squares
                                picNext.Image = 
My.Resources.Dark_Square_HighLightedMove
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        'One place
                    End If
                ElseIf strPiece = "White Rook" Then

                ElseIf strPiece = "White Knight" Then

                ElseIf strPiece = "White Bishop" Then

                ElseIf strPiece = "White Queen" Then

                Else 'White King

                End If
            End If
        Else

        End If
        'Check for Check
        'If so, Check for Win
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnReset.Click
    'Clear

    'Reset
    Static picPictureBox(,) As PictureBox = {{pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, 
pic7, pic8},
                                            {pic9, pic10, pic11, pic12, pic13, 
pic14, pic15, pic16},
                                            {pic17, pic18, pic19, pic20, pic21, 
pic22, pic23, pic24},
                                            {pic25, pic26, pic27, pic28, pic29, 
pic30, pic31, pic32},
                                            {pic33, pic34, pic35, pic36, pic37, 
pic38, pic39, pic40},
                                            {pic41, pic42, pic43, pic44, pic45, 
pic46, pic47, pic48},
                                            {pic49, pic50, pic51, pic52, pic53, 
pic54, pic55, pic56},
                                            {pic57, pic58, pic59, pic60, pic61, 
pic62, pic63, pic64}}
    strBoard(0, 0) = "Black Rook"
    strBoard(0, 1) = "Black Knight"
    strBoard(0, 2) = "Black Bishop"
    strBoard(0, 3) = "Black Queen"
    strBoard(0, 4) = "Black King"
    strBoard(0, 5) = "Black Bishop"
    strBoard(0, 6) = "Black Knight"
    strBoard(0, 7) = "Black Rook"
    For intIndex = 0 To 7
        strBoard(1, intIndex) = "Black Pawn"
        strBoard(6, intIndex) = "White Pawn"
    Next intIndex
    strBoard(7, 0) = "White Rook"
    strBoard(7, 1) = "White Knight"
    strBoard(7, 2) = "White Bishop"
    strBoard(7, 3) = "White Queen"
    strBoard(7, 4) = "White King"
    strBoard(7, 5) = "White Bishop"
    strBoard(7, 6) = "White Knight"
    strBoard(7, 7) = "White Rook"
    blnWhite = True
    bln1stClick = True
End Sub

Private Sub frmChess_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Static picPictureBox(,) As PictureBox = {{pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, 
pic7, pic8},
                                            {pic9, pic10, pic11, pic12, pic13, 
pic14, pic15, pic16},
                                            {pic17, pic18, pic19, pic20, pic21, 
pic22, pic23, pic24},
                                            {pic25, pic26, pic27, pic28, pic29, 
pic30, pic31, pic32},
                                            {pic33, pic34, pic35, pic36, pic37, 
pic38, pic39, pic40},
                                            {pic41, pic42, pic43, pic44, pic45, 
pic46, pic47, pic48},
                                            {pic49, pic50, pic51, pic52, pic53, 
pic54, pic55, pic56},
                                            {pic57, pic58, pic59, pic60, pic61, 
pic62, pic63, pic64}}
    strBoard(0, 0) = "Black Rook"
    strBoard(0, 1) = "Black Knight"
    strBoard(0, 2) = "Black Bishop"
    strBoard(0, 3) = "Black Queen"
    strBoard(0, 4) = "Black King"
    strBoard(0, 5) = "Black Bishop"
    strBoard(0, 6) = "Black Knight"
    strBoard(0, 7) = "Black Rook"
    For intIndex = 0 To 7
        strBoard(1, intIndex) = "Black Pawn"
        strBoard(6, intIndex) = "White Pawn"
    Next intIndex
    strBoard(7, 0) = "White Rook"
    strBoard(7, 1) = "White Knight"
    strBoard(7, 2) = "White Bishop"
    strBoard(7, 3) = "White Queen"
    strBoard(7, 4) = "White King"
    strBoard(7, 5) = "White Bishop"
    strBoard(7, 6) = "White Knight"
    strBoard(7, 7) = "White Rook"
    blnWhite = True
    bln1stClick = True
End Sub
End Class

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ6Wm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CklD0.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OAm6.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDsu0.png
```

Answer (score 0):

## Instead of grabbing the image, I have put all of the pictureboxes into an array. Using the array, I can use my intPlace variable to grab an index from the array.

Example:
Tiles(intPlace-8).Image = My.Resources.Light_Square_HighLightedMove

This allowed me to grab the index of the first picturebox I clicked on, then grab the next picturebox by subtracting 8 from the index, and finally change the properties of the new picturebox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).